# Converting text file into dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, text-files, valueerror

I have a text file similar to this:

```
banana
delicious
yellow

watermelon
big
red

orange
juicy
vitamin c
```

---

And I'm trying to convert this text file as dictionary (fruit names as key and its few lines of descriptions as various values). Following is my current code.

```
f = open("filepath", 'w')
myplant = {}
for line in f:
    k, v = line.strip().split('\n\n')
    myplant[k.strip()] = v.strip()
f.close()
```

But I got the following error:

```
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Can anyone help me debug my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you iterate over `f`, you are *iterating over lines delimited by `'\n'`*, so there will *never be `'\n\n'` in a single line, only ever one, so `.split('\n\n')` will never have two value, because there is no occurrence of `'\n\n'` in the `line`. That is the source of your error.

The following is a "cute" way to solve this. I encourage you to figure out another approach on your own, though.

```
In [1]: !cat filepath.txt
banana
delicious
yellow

watermelon
big
red

orange
juicy
vitamin c


In [2]: import itertools

In [3]: result = {}
   ...: with open('filepath.txt') as f:
   ...:     for empty_line, group in itertools.groupby(f, lambda x: x == '\n'):
   ...:         if empty_line:
   ...:             continue
   ...:         fruit, *desc = map(str.strip, group)
   ...:         result[fruit] = desc
   ...:

In [4]: result
Out[4]:
{'banana': ['delicious', 'yellow'],
 'watermelon': ['big', 'red'],
 'orange': ['juicy', 'vitamin c']}
```

Answer (score 5):

- Shortest Solution (Before the question was edited):

---

```
myplant = dict((i[0], i[1:3]) for i in (line.strip().split('\\n') for line in f if line != '\n') if i)
print(myplant)
```

Output:

```
{'banana ': [' delicious ', ' yellow '], 
 'watermelon ': [' big ', ' red '], 
 'orange ': [' juicy ', ' vitamin c ']}
```

- Generic Solution:

---

We can get all the values until the newline `\n` and store it in a temporary list. Then store it into the data list.

```
temporary = []

for line in f:
    if line.strip().split('\\n')[0]:
        if len(line.strip().split('\\n')) > 2:
            temporary = list(i.strip() for i in line.strip().split('\\n') if i.strip())
        else:
            temporary.append(line.strip().split('\\n')[0])
    elif temporary:
        data.append(temporary)
        temporary = []
```

The result will be:

```
[['banana', 'delicious', 'yellow'], 
 ['watermelon', 'big', 'red'], 
 ['orange', 'juicy', 'vitamin c']]
```

Now for each list, the first item will be the key and the rest are values.

```
myplant = dict((val[0], val[1:]) for val in data)
```

Output:

```
{'banana': ['delicious', 'yellow'], 
 'watermelon': ['big', 'red'], 
 'orange': ['juicy', 'vitamin c']}
```

- Detailed Explanation:

---

You should use `r` when you are reading from the text file

---

```py
f = open("filepath", 'r')
```

The key, value tuple is used when you are returning the dictionary items.

```
k = line.strip().split('\\n')
```

You could use `k.remove("")` to remove empty strings.

- Long way:

  ```py
  while "" in k:
      k.remove("")
  ```
- Short way:

  ```
  k = [i for i in k if i]
  ```
- Output:

---

```
{'banana ': [' delicious ', ' yellow '], 
 'watermelon ': [' big ', ' red '], 
 'orange ': [' juicy ', ' vitamin c ']}
```

- Code:

---

```
f = open("filepath", 'r')
myplant = {}
for line in f:
    k = line.strip().split('\\n')
    # while "" in k:
    #     k.remove("")
    k = [i for i in k if i]
    if k:
        myplant[k[0]] = k[1:]
print(myplant)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you opened the file in "w" which is write mode for the same. Which causes the problem in the for loop. You should use 'r' when performing read-only operations.